# How to log mysql error via cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, cakephp, logging

In my cakephp controller I have following piece of code

```
if (is_bool($data_model->save($entry))) 
{
    CakeLog::write('fcshell', "Failed to saved contact data.");
} 
else 
{
    CakeLog::write('fcshell', "Successfully saved contact data ";
}
```

Now I want to print/check mysql error/warning logs along with "Failed to save" line in fcshell.log file.

Only one I was able to reproduce the problem on one of the test instance which was "mysql server has gone away" but later could not reproduce the same error and on production some error still exists. I need to be sure if I am solving the correct mysql error.

If I make debug equal to 2 in core.php on production, it will print errors on web pages.

Can someone help me find a way to get mysql debug logs with fcshell logs OR any other way to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html), `save` normally fails when there is a validation problem.

You can log `$data_model->validationErrors` instead of trying to log the SQL query. If there is model validation error, the `save` query will not run.

Try something like

```
CakeLog::write('fcshell', "Failed to saved contact data." . var_export($data_model->validationErrors, true));
```

Comment: Only one I was able to reproduce the problem on one of the test instance which was "mysql server has gone away" but later could not reproduce the same error and on production some error still exists. I need to be sure if I am solving the correct mysql error.